# Correlations, Scatter Plots and P-Value

Tags: r, correlation, p-value

I have a set of data, after questioning customers.(it's about a shoe company) Two of the columns include GENDER and INCOME. I am supposed to test if there are any significant differences in income between genders, and give the corresponding P-value.

I'm still a n00b when it comes to R, I'm still learning and I've been struggling for 3 days now to find the functions to do so. Does anyone have any lead, or could help me with it? would be awesome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Take a minute to read through these tips on creating a [minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this post on creating a [great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and then tell us what you tried and provide a sample set of data. As it stands, your question is quite broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am editing this because I realized my other answer was not correct.

What you want is a linear model.

say

```
GENDER <- factor(c(0,1,1,0,1)
INCOME <- c(20000,30000,40000,50000,550000)
```

then you want

```
model <-lm(INCOME~GENDER)
```

and

```
summary(model)
anova(model)
```

will give you the information you are after.

Good luck,
Bryan